# Naming variables in recursive functions

Tags: php, function, naming-conventions

My recursive function **receives** the variable `$a` as an argument, **memorizes** it as `$b`, then **passes** it to itself.

#### Question:

If I recursively call a function, can the variable I pass to the recursive call (line 4 of the function) have the same name as the memorized variable (line 1 of the function)?

**Example 1**

```
$a = "bob";

function do_someting($b)
{
    echo $b;
    if ($b == 'bob') {
        do_something($b);
    }
}

do_something($a);
```

Or must I pass a variable with a different name (lines 4 and 5 of this function)?

**Example 2**

```
function do_someting($b)
{
    echo $b;
    if ($b == 'bob') {
        $c = $b;
        do_something($c);
    }
}
```

The function, as it is given here, will cause an infinite loop. This is not my real code, just an example to illustrate my question. **Don't run it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at variable scopes : [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Inside a function you reuse the variable name inside the scope, scope being start-end of function. If you call function recursively then inner scopes do not effect outer scope.

Consider function:

```
function decrements($b) {
   print "pre call $b={$b}\n\r";
   if($b>0) decrements(--$b);
   print "post call $b={$b}\n\r";
}

decrements(4);
```

Output would be:

```
pre call 4=4
pre call 3=3
pre call 2=2
pre call 1=1
pre call 0=0
post call 0=0
post call 0=0
post call 1=1
post call 2=2
post call 3=3
```

And if you insert $b = 4

```
decrements($b) { //$b = 4
  decrements($b) { //$b = 3
    decrements($b) { //$b = 2
      decrements($b) { //$b = 1
        decrements($b) { //$b = 0
        } //$b = 0
      } //$b = 0
    } //$b = 1
  } //$b = 2
} //$b = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Example 1 would run fine. When you pass $b, the receiving function receives only a copy of $b and therefore when the receiving function modifies it, it won't affect the original $b.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Example1 without any problem.

The variable `$b` is within the scope of your function, so it's available everywhere within the function.

Since you're calling your function again you can think of a new instance (even technically `instance` isn't the right word to describe it i guess, but for explaination it works) is created from that function. This instance doesn't have a clue that the `$b` he recieved is the same and named the same as the instance before.

Also because you didn't paste them by reference any changes to `$b` in one function call won't change anything in the other calls, but in the calls that will be called from the function where you changed `$b`. So what that means is if you would give them in per reference `$a` would be changed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to pass the variable with a different name.
The variable `$b` "lives" just inside the function. So if you call the function again